# SQL Multiple Table Join - Best Optimization

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, where-clause, ssrs-2012

Hi am hoping someone can help my SQL theory out. I have to create a set of reports which use joins from multiple tables. These reports are running far slower than I would like and I am hoping to optimize my SQL although my knowledge has hit a wall and I cant seem to find anything on Google.

I am hoping someone here can give me some best practice guidance.

Essentially I am trying to filter on the results set as it comes back to reduce the number of rows included in later joins

```
Items INNER JOIN BlueItems ON Items.ItemID = BlueItems.ItemID AND BlueItems.shape = 'square'
          LEFT JOIN ItemHistory ON Items.ItemID = ItemHistory.ItemsID
          LEFT JOIN ItemDates ON Items.ItemID = ItemDates.ItemID
WHERE ItemDates.ManufactureDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/05/2017'
```

I figure that Inner Joining on Blue items that are squares vastly reduces the data set at this point?

I also understand that the Where clause is intelligent enough to reduce the data set on run time? Am I mistaken? Is it returning all the data and then just filtering on that data?

Any guidance on essentially how to speed this kind of query up would be fantastic, Index's and such have already been put in place. Unfortunately the database is actually looked after by someone else and I am simply creating reports based on their database. This does limit me to just being able to optimize my queries rather than the data itself.

I guess at this point its time for me to try and improve my knowledge on how SQL handles the various ways you can filter on data and try to understand which actually reduce the dataset used and which simply filter on it. Any guidance would be very appreciated!

Comment: `Index's and such have already been put in place` ... can you show/tell us what you have done with regards to indexing?

Comment: Hi Tim, that side of things is out of my remit but essentially I can see that an Index exists on the Primary Key fields such as all the ItemID fields. Unfortunately the database is actually looked after by someone else and I am simply creating reports based on their database. This does limit me to just being able to optimize my queries rather than the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the primary keys are all indexed, but this is always the case for primary key fields.  The only portion of your current query which would possibly benefit from this is the first join with `Items`.  For the other joins and the `WHERE` clause, these primary key fields are not being used.

For this particular query, I would suggest the following indices:

```
ALTER TABLE BlueItems   ADD INDEX bi_item_idx (ItemID, shape)
ALTER TABLE ItemHistory ADD INDEX ih_item_idx (ItemID)
ALTER TABLE ItemDates   ADD INDEX id_idx      (ItemID, ManufactureDate)
```

For the `ItemHistory` table, the index `ih_item_idx` should speed up the join involving the `ItemID` foreign key.  A column by the same name is also involved with the other two joins, and hence is part of the other indices.  The reason for the composite indices (i.e. indices involving more than one column) is that we want to cover all the columns which appear in either the join or the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hi Tim, 
Thanks for the advice but I guess I am keen to learn more about how it works at the query level. Even with Optimized Index'ing I am wonder if the WHERE clause is generally better or worse to use than doing a join and only including the relevant data at that stage. I guess I am also keen to know how the ordering of WHERE affects how much data is being processed and that kind of thing.

Comment: You only have one condition in your `WHERE` clause, so ordering should be irrelevant (and I don't think it matters in general).  Comparing `WHERE` to a join is apples to oranges; they are very different things.  At this point, adding indices is probably the only major improvement you can make over your current performance.

Answer (score 0):

These comments are not really an answer but too big to put in a comment...

IF the dates being passed in as parameters (i'm guessing they are) then it might be parameter sniffing that is causing the issue. The query may be using a bad plan.

I've seen this a lot especially when using the `between` operator. A few quick things to try as adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query. This might seem counter intuitive but just try it. Although compiled queries should be faster than recompiling, if a bad plan is being used, it can slow things down A LOT.

Also, If ItemDates is big, try dumping yuor filtered results to a temp table and joining to that, so something like.

```
SELECT * INTO #id FROM ItemDates i WHERE i.ManufactureDate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/05/2017'
```

The change you main query to be something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Items 
    JOIN BlueItems ON Items.ItemID = BlueItems.ItemID AND BlueItems.shape = 'square'
    JOIN #id i ON Items.ItemID = i.ItemID
    LEFT JOIN ItemHistory ON Items.ItemID = ItemHistory.ItemsID
```

I also changed the JOIN from being a `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN` (implicitly an inner join) as you are only selecting items which have a match in `ItemDates` so `LEFT` joining makes no sense.